# When does radiation actually happen?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

When does a body actually starts radiating:

1. either above absolute zero temperature, all bodies start radiating?
2. or when it absorbs heat from surrounding and then increases its temperature, then it starts radiating?

When does it actually happen? My university professor gave the first reason, but when I found a video about it the second reason was given so now I am a bit confused. Can someone tell which reason mentioned above is correct?

Comment: This is more or less the chicken or egg question except for the fact that absolutely zero has never been reached or found in nature so everything is already radiating.

Comment: Hi Aadorika. All bodies above absolute zero radiate, so (1) is true, but bodies only have a temperature above absolute zero if they can absorb heat from their surroundings, so (2) is true as well.

Comment: Tq John  Rennie sir for clearing my doubt:)))